# Jquery checkbox render data on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Hi I have a widget that pops up when a button is clicked, and on this widget some data is provided. I created a check box call `archiveLog`. When this checkbox is checked I want the data to render. Here is what i have:

```
dataServiceStudy.getLogsByStudyId(studyId)
                .done(function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        var studyLogTitle = "something " + somethingId;
                        var modalDiv = "somethingLog" + somethingId;
                        modalsHelper.getModalPartial("/loc1/subloc1/subsubloc1",
                        null,
                        new Object(),
                        { "height": "400", "width": "750", "name": modalDiv, "title": somethingLogTitle })
                        .done(function () {
                            renderStudyLogGrid();
                            $("#archiveLog").change(function () {
                                if (this.checked) {
                                    bindStudyLog(result);
                                }
                            })
                            //bindStudyLog(result);
                            $('#closeStudyLog').click(function () {
                                $('#' + modalDiv).dialog('close');
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
```

when the checkbox is check the data does not appear

EDIT****

I want it to refresh the grid once its checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
$("#archiveLog").on(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        bindStudyLog(result);
    }
})
```

with:

```
$("#archiveLog").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        bindStudyLog(result);
    } else {
        //hide block
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be **Change**

```
 $("#archiveLog").change(function () {

       //Add your logic here

    });
```